# is there a way to shorten prefences list in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

is there a way to set this in one line 
by example

appwindow(setContentSize(NSSize(width: 400, height: 23),titlebarAppearsTransparent = true) ect

rather than having to spell them one by one

```
    appWindow.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 400, height: 23))
    appWindow.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    appWindow.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    appWindow.backgroundColor =  NSColor.white //Maybe have it gray instead so we can remove this?
    appWindow.setFrameAutosaveName(NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName(rawValue: "myGoodGoodApp"))
    appWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    appWindow.contentView?.addSubview(gunTrigger)
```

Comment: Nop there isn't, the only thing you could do is make a function

Comment: Why do you wish to put it all on one line? It's must easier to read, debug, and change the code when it is on separate lines.

Comment: @maddy it just seem professial app wouldnt have it this way i cant recal seeing pro apps who do it this way

Comment: @ValW  a function like a forEach with $0 ?

Comment: No I mean that you put the whole modifications into an function and then just call the function in case you just want to improve the readability in the code section where that snippet is.

Comment: Btw putting it in one line seems way unprofessional then that way. professional != complicated. Easy to read code is mostly good code.

Comment: so you're saying the way i have it now is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an immediately executed closure to give yourself a scope in which you can have a short variable name, while allowing you to preserve a better, longer name in the rest of the usage. It's a particularly useful technique for value types, as this allows you to keep the mutability constrained to the closure.

```
let appWindow: NSWindow = {
    let w = NSWindow()
    w.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 400, height: 23))
    w.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    w.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    w.backgroundColor =  NSColor.white //Maybe have it gray instead so we can remove this?
    w.setFrameAutosaveName(NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName(rawValue: "myGoodGoodApp"))
    w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    w.contentView?.addSubview(gunTrigger)
    return w
}()
```